# Change weights of the portfolio

Tags: finance, portfolio-optimization, quantitative, investment

I have spent a lot of time finding some trading alphas. Now, I have about 10 alphas to trade Future, I also optimized the portfolio by using Markowitz's Modern Portfolio Theory (MPT) to get weights. However, I think I can optimize more than by auto-change weights with the different patterns of the market. I have searched the papers about this problem. But I can't find using paper. Can you help me, please! Thank you so much.

Comment: *"I think I can optimize more than by auto-change weights with the different patterns of the market"*, would you care to elaborate how you think you can optimize your portfolio setup better? Depending on the portfolio setup, you can estimate the covariance matrix using higher sampling frequencies, a "better" volatility model etc to get a more accurate estimate, and thus get better weights (if you want to put your faith into MPT).